# toISOString not working with Cordova Ionic in iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, angularjs, cordova

I am using Cordova Ionic framework to develop apps in Android and iOS. In my requirement, I want to show the month and date in page. I have a date from service my code is like this controller:

```
.controller('groupMessagesCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Services) {

    Services.getGroupMessage($stateParams).then(function(data){
        $scope.groupMessage = data.data;
    });

    $scope.toISOString = function(x){
        return new Date(x).toISOString();
    };

})
```

In HTML page

```
<div class="list messages_list">
  <a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="Message in groupMessage" href="#/app/message/{{Message.CS_MESSAGE_ID}}">
    <!--<p>{{Message}}</p>-->
    <img src="img/sample/venkman.jpg">
    <!-- Adding the user name to the message-->
    <h2><span class="date">{{toISOString(Message.CS_RECEIVED_DATE)}}</span>{{Message.CS_FIRST_NAME +" "+Message.CS_LAST_NAME}}</h2>
    <p>{{Message.CS_MSG}}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am getting the undefined error when calling `toISOString()` function in iPhone app only. Except iPhone, in all browsers and Android apps working good.

Comment: What is *x*? String? Number? Format? If it's a string, then parsing of strings using the Date constructor is extremely unreliable. Very simple to write your own parser (one more line of code in your *toISOString* function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here x is date string.

the Date is not working in safari browser with passing the string, that x is replacing with /-/g to /

code is return new Date(x.replace(/-/g, "/")).toISOString();

.controller('groupMessagesCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Services) {

```
Services.getGroupMessage($stateParams).then(function(data){
    $scope.groupMessage = data.data;
});

$scope.toISOString = function(x){
    return new Date(x.replace(/-/g, "/")).toISOString();
};
```

})

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `$scope` has no `Message` object. I little bit confuse, where is your code that represent `Message` object, but I assume your `Message` object is a child of `groupMessage`, so your `controller` should be something like:

```
Services.getGroupMessage($stateParams).then(function(data){
  $scope.groupMessage = data.data; // I assume it's an array
  $scope.Message = $scope.groupMessage[0]; // It's an example to defining an `Message` object
});
```

I give an example to create a `Message` object from your array and assume it's a `date` object. In your HTML simply put:

```
{{Message.toISOString()}}
```

Without creating a new method just to get `ISOString` from a date.